# Google Custom Search with XSLT

Tags: xslt, search-engine

I'm trying to implement the google custom search engine to a website running with xslt.

This code is located in the head section

```
(function() {
    var cx = '..............';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

And this snippet in the body

```
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

But i only get following error **Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Namespace prefix google on search is not defined**

Some idea why? Do i need a special xmlns?

Cheers

Comment: Please provide more details, which browser gives that error message? Have you tried other browsers? If you simply serve a HTML document with that Javascript code, does the code work as you want? Or do you get the same error message? We need to identify whether the problem is related to XSLT at all. Is the XSLT done server-side or client-side?

Comment: Hi. It's the same in Firefox 14.0.1, Safari 6.0 and Chrome 21.0.1180.82. The JavaScript Code seems to be ok, the error only apears, if i paste the gcse element. The XSLT is done server-side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am trying to make sense of https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#overview and your posted question. I am kind of guessing but based on https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5 try to replace `<gcse:search></gcse:search>` in your code with `<div class="gcse-search"></div>`, that way I hope your XSLT input is namespace well-formed and your attempt to include the Google search in the transformation result works.

Answer (score 1):

Just bringing out how to ***add attributes*** example from the links shared by Martin above:

#### HTML5-valid div tags

You can use HTML5-valid div tags as long as you observe these guidelines:

- The class attribute must be set to ***gcse-XXX***
- Any attributes must be prefixed with ***data-***.

For example:

```html
<div class="gcse-searchbox" data-resultsUrl="http://www.example.com"
     data-newWindow="true" data-queryParameterName="search" >
```